# Canceling login credentials, will call SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased case

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I implemented IAP in my app with this code:

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        [_loadingIndicator startAnimating];

        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self unlockPurchase];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;

                case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self unlockPurchase];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;

                case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                NSLog(@"Transaction failed");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

When purchase button is pressed and an alert view pops up and asks for Apple ID and password, if user presses Cancel button, the code goes into `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:` case and the app unlocks the product. What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was going on. Local IAP Store tweak from Cydia was running. 
I installed it to check if it is possible to bypass ITunes Store with this tweak and find a workaround to prevent it and then I forgot to turn it off.